# I can't read a public array in C#

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I have a project called FoodPantryGlobal, which contains all of the constants I will use.
I have another project called RegisterInput which uses FoodPantryGlobal.
In FoodPantryGlobal is an array called CityNames[], that RegisterInput needs to use in order to load a Combobox.

The problem I am having is CityNames[] seems to be empty to RegisterInput when called.

If I declare a local array, and use that every thing works fine.

I am betting it is something simple that I am missing.
FoodPantryGlobal has been added to the resources.

```
using System;
```

The code I am using for the Global.

```
namespace FoodPantryGlobals
{
    public class GlobalConst
    {
        public const string excelFileName = "Food Pantry Registry.xlsm";
        public const int cityNamesMembers = 4;
        public readonly string[] cityNames = new string[cityNamesMembers] {"Hollans", "Roanoke", "Salem", "Vinton" };
    }
    public class GlobalProcedures
    {

    }
}
```

The code making trying to use CityNames.

```
using FoodPantryGlobals;

private void CboxCity_GotFocus(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int members = GlobalConst.cityNamesMembers;
    //string[] cityNames = new string[members] { "Hollans", "Roanoke", "Salem", "Vinton" };

    //string city = FoodPantryGlobals.GlobalConst.cityNames[0];
    int  index = 0;
    while (index < members)
    {
        string city = GlobalConst.cityNames[index];
        CboxCity.Items.Add(city);
        index = index + 1;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why do you add that class to the resources?

Comment: So I can read it in another project. I can see and use the other constants.

Answer (score 0):

Just make  cityNames static

```
public static readonly string[] cityNames = new string[] { "Hollans", "Roanoke", "Salem", "Vinton" };
```

and IMHO you can use foreach

```
foreach (var city in GlobalConst.cityNames) CboxCity.Items.Add(city);
```

or maybe even better

```
CboxCity.Items.AddRange( GlobalConst.cityNames);
```

maybe you should clear previous items before adding new ones

```
CboxCity.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: I just tried that and ended up with the same results.

Comment: @PaulaJoann I am always testing my code before posting. Everything working properly.

Comment: Is the `Items` property also an instance property?

Comment: @PaulaJoann So you have an answer here that explains why your `cityNames` isn't visible. You should learn why this fixes your problem and apply that to the issues you still see.

Comment: @PaulaJoann What error do you have now?

Comment: The array still turns up empty when accessed and used.

Comment: @PaulaJoann How do you know this? Did you use debugger? Since  you are using index you will get an exception immediately if array is empty.

Comment: I used the debugger and a message box.

Comment: And what about  GlobalConst.cityNames[index];??? if cityNames are null?

Comment: To me it appears to not be loading the array, or loading the 0 element with null. The code builds good does not give any error message on the build or running.

Comment: @PaulaJoann You would  get an exception immediately.